# Javascript Date object using variables

Tags: javascript, html, css

My js code is as follows:-

```
   var earlierdate=new Date(2012,09,22);
   alert(earlierdate.getDay());

   var date2 = new Date('2012,09,22');
   alert(date2.getDay());
```

The problem is first alert gives me 1 0r Monday(which is incorrect) and second one gives me 6 or sat which is correct. So date given in quotes is giving correct result. Now if want to use variables instead of hard-coded values like

```
var date1 = new Date(a,b,c);
alert(date1.getDay());
```

What should be the syntax. I have tried a lot of variations but failed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `month` parameter of `Date` is **0-indexed**.

> ***month***
>
> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to
>   11 for December.

So if you mean *September*, that should be `var earlierdate=new Date(2012, 8, 22);`

Answer (score 1):

```
 //Option 1
 var myDate=new Date();
 myDate.setFullYear(2010,0,14);

//Option 2 (Neater)
var myDate=new Date(2010,0,14);
```

This will set the time to 14th January 2010.